# Optimistic Lock @Version not working in Unit Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, liquibase

in my application Java - Spring Boot - Hibernate - Liquibase
On normal run checking version work correctly, and i get expected error during update with wrong version parameter.
But on Junit test Update pass regardless to version parameter

Should add something to my create Table in Liquibase?

```
@Version
private int version;
```

==================

```
@Test
void shouldNotUpdateDoctor_wrongVersion() throws Exception {
    UpdateDoctorCommand updateDoctorCommand
            = new UpdateDoctorCommand("test4update",LocalDate.of(1980, 5, 12),
            LocalDate.of(2020, 11, 10), 16000, true, 2,3);
    String requestJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(updateDoctorCommand);

    postman.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/api/v1/clinic/doctors/33")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(requestJson))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$").value("ROW_UPDATED_IN_ANOTHER_TRANSACTION"));

    postman.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/v1/clinic/doctors/33"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("notUpdated"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.version").value("5"));
}
```

=====

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<400> but was:<200>
Expected :400
Actual   :200
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding in test application:properties:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

solve problem